# Check the Checkbox through VBscript in IE webpage

Tags: checkbox, vbscript

I need to automate the check (Selecting) a checkbox in the IE webpage through vbscript.
I wrote some code for it, but it gives "Object Required" Error for document.getElementById("checkBox(IsAdmin)"),
Code Start:

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With oIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate ("link")
      wscript.sleep 500
End With
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim document
document.getElementById("checkBox(IsAdmin)")
Item(0).Checked = True
```

The HTML source code is like :

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: To post HTML, add an empty line before it and begin every line with four spaces. (I couldn't edit your post. It says I have to add more text - I don't want to add text.)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your `checkBox ID` is correct. Also `Document` is a `IE` object member.

```
oIE.Document.getElementById("IsAdmin").Checked = True
```